# Radio button and request.getParameter

Tags: java, html

I have a radio button really simple in my html file:

```
<form role="form" method="post" action="jsp/site/Portal.jsp?page=mypage">
    <input type="radio"  id="radio_1" name="name_radio" value="value1" />
    <input type="radio" id="radio_2" name="name_radio" value="value2" />
    <button name="action_validateForm" type="submit">
        Valider
    </button>
</form>
```

But when i send the form it goes in function :

```
@Action( ACTION_VALIDATE_FORM )
public Page doValidateForm( HttpServletRequest request ) 
{
   String valueGet = request.getParameter( "name_radio" );

    if ( valueGet.equals( "value1" ) )
    {
        //Do action
    }
    else if ( valueGet.equals( "value2" ) )
    {
        //Do other action
    }    
}
```

The problem is that no matter the radio button I select before validate the form when I check `request.getParameter( "name_radio" )` the value is always false. How can it be possible? it should be value1, value2 or null?

Comment: how could you get false value for this request.getParameter( "name_radio" )?

Comment: It's my question i absolutly don't understand when i launch in debug mode and i check the value it's false ... i am lost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to add submit button or javascript code to submit your form, then try to fetch radio button value in JSP.

see i have added submit button.

```
<form role="form" method="post" action="jsp/site/Portal.jsp?page=mypage">
    <input type="radio"  id="radio_1" name="name_radio" value="value1" />
    <input type="radio" id="radio_2" name="name_radio" value="value2" />
    <button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Sorry i don't put it on my code but i already have a submit button i will add it on my post

Comment: I check and finally it was a stupid error with the submit button thank khAn